# How to decompose Max(X) which is permutation invariant function in the form ρ(∑x∈X φ(x)) , for suitable transformations φ and ρ?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, invariant-theory

I went through a theorem which is given below-
"A function S(X) operating on a set X can be a valid scoring function, i.e. it is permutation invariant to the elements in X, if and only if it can be decomposed in the form ρ(∑x∈X φ(x)) , for suitable transformations φ and ρ." The theorem can be found here - https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06114

Since Max(X) is obviously a permutation invariant function i.e it is not affected by order of elements in a set hence it can be broken down in this form. So what will be φ and ρ in this case?

Comment: Fixed the question

Comment: It is nor clear in that paper what the domain of $\varphi $ or of $\rho $ is supposed to be. For instance, it is not clear if $\varphi $ is only to be defined on the specific set $X $ under consideration. If that is the case, you can define $\varphi (x)=0$ unless $x=\operatorname {Max}(X) $, in which case $\varphi (x)=x $. And $\rho  ( a)=a $. Modify $\rho $ appropriately if these are multisets, so that the maximum may appear several times in $X $.

Comment: Could we define a φ such that it is not piece-wise function?

Comment: Why? What difference would that make? It seems completely irrelevant.

Comment: IMO, in the paper, $\rho$ and $\phi$ are trainable functions. They are obtained from training with a specific task.